# Django How to choose one field of a ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm with two TextAreas, so, on the view, I want to decide which of both use (Before I defined two ModelForms, one per field, but it's a lot of duplicate code.

Here's the ModelForm:

```
class f_post_comment(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['commentCreator', 'commentReceiver']
    widgets = {
        'commentCreator': forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Write your comment for your post'
            }
        ),
        'commentReceiver': forms.Textarea(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Write your comment for the post you\'ve received'
            }
        ),
    }
```

And here's how I use in the view:

```
@login_required
def commentpost(request, id_post):
    try:
        favor = Favor.objects.get(id=id_favor)
    except Favor.DoesNotExist:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Post doesn't exists")
        return redirect('home')

    option= None
    if request.user == post.Creator:
        option = 'commentCreator'
    elif request.user == post.Receiver:
        option = 'commentReceiver'
    formBasic = modelform_factory(Post, form=f_post_comment, fields=(option,))
    if option is not None:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = formBasic(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                form.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Thanks for the comment.")
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                                      "Can't make an empty comment.")
        else:
            form = formBasic
            return render(request, 'posts/commentpost.html', {'post': post, 'form': form})
    else:
        messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR,
                             "You are neither the Creator nor the Receiver of this post")
    return redirect('home')
```

Any ideas?

And what about the template?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One simpler approach might be to create a base ModelForm class for Post with the common functionality, then create 2 subclasses for the creator and receiver.

When inheriting from a modelform you can also inherit the Meta object from the parent Meta - see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#form-inheritance

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain properly, I edited my question, because my view is larger...